# The Current Page command not return the correct Page number value

Tags: page-numbering

I'll try to get the Each paragraph starting and Ending Page numbers. But, I can't get the correct page number for each page first paragraph. I have mentioned the below MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\ptag{m}{\bgroup%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \coordinate (here) at (0,0);%
        \protect\draw (current page.west |- here) node[right]{{\textbf{PID:#1-PST:\theCurrentPage}}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\egroup%
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\etag{m}{\bgroup%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \coordinate (here) at (0,0);%
        \protect\draw (current page.west |- here) node[right]{{\textbf{PID:#1-PED:\theCurrentPage}}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\egroup%
}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Lipsum Content}

\ptag{1}\lipsum[1]\etag{1}

\ptag{2}\lipsum[2]\etag{2}

\ptag{3}\lipsum[3]\etag{3}

\ptag{4}\lipsum[4]\etag{4}

\ptag{5}\lipsum[5]\etag{5}

\ptag{6}\lipsum[6]\etag{6}

\ptag{7}\lipsum[7]\etag{7}

\ptag{8}\lipsum[8]\etag{8}

\ptag{9}\lipsum[9]\etag{9}

\ptag{10}\lipsum[10]\etag{10}

\ptag{11}\lipsum[11]\etag{11}

\ptag{12}\lipsum[12]\etag{12}

\ptag{13}\lipsum[13]\etag{13}

\ptag{14}\lipsum[14]\etag{14}

\ptag{15}\lipsum[15]\etag{15}


\end{document}
```

The output PDF terms like `PID - para ID, PST - Para Start Page Number, PED - Para End Page Number`. I have mentioned the wrong `Para End Page Number` for the below image. This error continues the consecutive page.

[image]

How to get the exact real page numbers using "pageslts" package. How it is happen. How to resolve this error. Please check and advise

Comment: You must use labels and pageref if you want to retrieve page numbers in a reliable way.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer label and pageref working well. But i can't get the real page numbers like `\theCurrentPage` command output. If i am using mixed page numbering like `frontmatter` (roman), `mainmatter` (arabic) contents, in this case the real PDF page numbers is very useful for me. If any similar command is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own page counter, but you will need a custom version of `\label` in order to delay expansion until printed.  `\pageref` will still return `\thepage`.

Note that this is incompatible with hyperref or any other package which modifies `\newlabel`.  Then again, hyperref has its own page count `\Hy@abspage`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{realpage}
\setcounter{realpage}{1}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\stepcounter{realpage}}

\makeatletter
\def\realpagelabel#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{\let\therealpage=\relax}% delay expansion
   {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\therealpage}{\thepage}}}%
\@esphack}
\makeatother

\DeclareDocumentCommand\ptag{m}{\realpagelabel{ptag#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \coordinate (here) at (0,0);
        \draw (current page.west |- here) node[right]{\textbf{PID:#1-PST:\ref{ptag#1}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\etag{m}{\realpagelabel{etag#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \coordinate (here) at (0,0);
        \draw (current page.west |- here) node[right]{{\textbf{PID:#1-PED:\ref{etag#1}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Lipsum Content}

\ptag{1}\lipsum[1]\etag{1}

\ptag{2}\lipsum[2]\etag{2}

\ptag{3}\lipsum[3]\etag{3}

\ptag{4}\lipsum[4]\etag{4}

\ptag{5}\lipsum[5]\etag{5}

\ptag{6}\lipsum[6]\etag{6}

\ptag{7}\lipsum[7]\etag{7}

\ptag{8}\lipsum[8]\etag{8}

\ptag{9}\lipsum[9]\etag{9}

\ptag{10}\lipsum[10]\etag{10}

\ptag{11}\lipsum[11]\etag{11}

\ptag{12}\lipsum[12]\etag{12}

\ptag{13}\lipsum[13]\etag{13}

\ptag{14}\lipsum[14]\etag{14}

\ptag{15}\lipsum[15]\etag{15}


\end{document}
```